# Understanding has_one :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, console

I am studying Active Record Associations documentation for a [has_one :through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association) in rails and doing some experimenting in the console based on the Account/Supplier/AccountHistory example.

So if I do something like this...

```
@supplier = Supplier.create(name: "Acme")
 => #<Supplier id: 1, name: "Acme", ...>

 @supplier.create_account(account_number: "123")
 => #<Account id: 1, supplier_id: 1, account_number: "123", ...>

  @account = @supplier.account
 => #<Account id: 1, supplier_id: 1, account_number: "123", ...>

 @account.create_account_history(credit_rating: 456)
 => #<AccountHistory id: 1, account_id: 1, credit_rating: 456, ...>

 @supplier.account_history
 => #<AccountHistory id: 1, account_id: 1, credit_rating: 456, ...>
```

I see only a single record is returned. Makes sense. Now if I do this...

```
@supplier.account.create_account_history(credit_rating: 789)
 => #<AccountHistory id: 2, account_id: 1, credit_rating: 789, ...>

 @supplier.account_history
 => #<AccountHistory id: 2, account_id: 1, credit_rating: 789, ...>
```

Again, only a single record is returned. In this case, the new record that has a credit rating of 789.

Two questions. First, does this example do a good job of encapsulating the purpose of a has_one :through association? The whole point being that a single record/object is returned rather than an array of objects that you would get from a has_many association?

Second, how does the association decide what single record to return? In the example above there are now two records in the AccountHistory table:

```
AccountHistory.all
  AccountHistory Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "account_histories".* FROM "account_histories"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<AccountHistory id: 1, account_id: nil, credit_rating: 456, ...>, #<AccountHistory id: 2, account_id: 1, credit_rating: 789, ...>]>
```

Does the call to `@supplier.account_history` simply return the last record inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put in the console `AccountHistory.all`, the answer is a relation

1.- for has_one: through is ok because only one record is associated with another one, i.e. a Supplier can have an AccountHistory only if the Account exists because the Account and the AccountHistory are related.

2.- The association knows the returned object via the id of the associated table, this means the account_id of the account, if you check the output in the terminal, you have two records, but one is nil and the other is associated with your Account 1

> account_id: nil

, credit_rating: 456, ...>, #

> account_id: 1

, credit_rating: 789, ...>]>

So if you put in console `@account = Account.find(1)` and then `@account.account_history.credit_rating` you will have 789.

Comment: Boom! Great answer Daniel. The `nil` field in account_id totally escaped me. Good catch!!!